# How to do Importing and exporting excel using C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have an Excel file which is generated by a machine. I need to create an application using WPF and C# which can import the excel to see its contents, do some calculations and create some new columns and save back as new excel file. Which is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Microsoft's [Open XML library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) (as it doesn't require Excel to be installed).

There are various 3rd party libraries that sit on top of it to make it easier to use; such as [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Consider ODBC Excel drivers. If your input file is built by machine AND you do not want anything fancy as output, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Spreadsheet control to open excel http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/spreadsheet

Sample location: http://silverlight.syncfusion.com/samples/WPF/Samples/WPFSampleBrowser/UI/Spreadsheet/Spreadsheet.htm